# HTML5 markup for a slideshow

Tags: html, slideshow, markup

I have a slideshow on my home page. The slideshow have no content, only background images.

The question: Should I mark it up as a section or anything else? Maybe skip the HTML5 markup?

```
<header></header>

<div id=slideshow></div>

<main></main>

<aside></aside>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: If you want a background slideshow I should give the `#slideshow` a negative `z-index` and a `position:fixed;`. For this slider don't you need the html5 markup but you can use it for the rest of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a DIV would be fine. You could use section if you have a header for the slider and maybe a paragraph also. It's a list of images, right? So make an UL with the images inside, and remove the bullets with CSS.